# Is there any way to do bidirectional communication in ios?

Tags: ios, ipc

Is there a way to enable two-way communication between a App created by developer A and app b created by developer B using a custom url scheme?

I want to call App b from App a and get the response value of App b from App a.

Or is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, if both developers agree on the url scheme to open app B and then have app B open app A again. The user will see the two apps bouncing back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The user will see the two apps bouncing back and forth. -> Is this the right development method? I want a smooth flow..

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a great approach, no, but it is all you have available in device. Generally it is better if app A can interact directly with App B's backend

Comment: According to the client's requirement, after calling App b from App a, App b must access the backend. Is there really no best way other than url scheme in IOS?

Comment: No, because in general only the foreground app is executing

Comment: If two clients want to share data with one another, a remote server is the only elegant way, unless the two clients have a unique relationship where a technology like Bluetooth can be used. To attempt to get around this could quickly become a mess.